# How do I concatenate string in java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

```
this.picture = "/memberdata/" + Integer.toString(ID) + ".png";
```

I have the class member and each member has a path for a profile pictures which is based on the ID of the member.

However whenever I try to use the code above I get the following message:

```
Incompatible Types
Required: "com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String"
Found: java.lang.string
```

I also tried `valueOf` to convert the `Integer` into a `String` and `.concat` but nothing seems to fix the problem. `picture` is defined as String

Comment: Guessing: Your IDE-auto-import messed up and you have `import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;` in your source file and that defines the type of `this.picture`

Comment: When asking questions regarding types you have to include context, e.g., what `this.picture` is defined as. Here it looks like you're attempting to directly modify an xpath string, which probably isn't what you should be doing.

Comment: @DaveNewton edited

Comment: Is it java.lang.String or "com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String". Try correcting the import.(Remove the other xpath String from import)

Comment: How `this.picture` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
```

Answer (score -1):

i deleted import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String and it seems to work now.